# $f$ is continuous, is $1/f$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Let $f: A \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous. Suppose there exist $k>0$ s.t. $|f(x)| \ge k$ for all $x \in A$. Show that the function $1/f$ is also uniformly continuous on $A$.

**My proof**

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since f is uniformly continuous, we obtain there exist $\delta > 0$

$|f(x) - f(y)| < k^2 \epsilon$, for any $|x-y| < \delta$

Therefore we obtain

$\left|\frac{1}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{f(y)}\right| = \left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{f(y)f(x)}\right| = \left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{f(y)f(x)}\right| < \frac{k^2 \epsilon}{k^2} = \epsilon$ for any $|x-y| < \delta$

Thus, $\frac{1}{f}$ is uniformly continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sticking to the question in the body, since the one in the title has a weaker hypothesis and a weaker thesis:*

Your proof works just fine.

Since short answers tend to be recognized automatically as low quality, I'll unnecessarily observe that this proof can be extended to $A$ being a generic metric space $(A,d)$ by substituting "$\lvert x-y\rvert<\epsilon$" with "$d(x,y)<\epsilon$" whenever this string occurs.