# Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then so is $\frac{1}{f}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb R^n $ , $f: E \to \mathbb R $ and $x_0 \in E $ with $f(x_0) \neq 0 $.
Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then so is $\frac{1}{f}$.

I understand I would use a proof similar to the one in this question:
[$f$ is continuous, is $1/f$ continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743501/f-is-continuous-is-1-f-continuous)

but I'm unsure how to adapt it for when $E\subseteq \mathbb R^n $.

Comment: The difference is that now $|x-y|$ means the norm of $x-y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, rather than the absolute value of $x-y$ (since now $x$ and $y$ are vectors, not real numbers). Also, you are only assuming continuity at one point, not uniform continuity on the entire domain.

Comment: I removed the tag *functional analysis* since your question does not fit into that category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that because $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)$ is nonzero, there is some $\delta>0$ such that, whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$, we have

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)| \leqslant  \frac 1 2 |f(x_0)|$$

Because $||x|-|y|| \leqslant |x-y|$ it follows that for this choice of $\delta$,

$$-\frac 1 2 |f(x_0)| \leqslant |f(x)|-|f(x_0)| \leqslant \frac 1 2 |f(x_0)|$$
so that $|f(x)| \geqslant \frac 1 2 |f(x_0)|$. In particular, $f$ is nonzero in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Given $\varepsilon >0$, choose $\delta>0$ so that  whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$ the following hold simultaneously 
\begin{align} 
\tag{1}|f(x)-f(x_0)|&< \frac 1 2 |f(x_0)| \\
\tag{2} |f(x)-f(x_0)|&< \frac \varepsilon 2|f(x_0)|^2
\end{align}

By the first remark, in a neighbourhood of zero $1/f$ is well defined, and

\begin{align*}
 \left| \frac{1}{f(x)}-\frac{1}{f(x_0)}\right | &= \frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)|}{|f(x)||f(x_0)|} \\
&\stackrel{(2)} \leqslant \frac 1{ |f(x_0)||f(x)|} \frac \varepsilon 2|f(x_0)|^2\\
&\stackrel{(1)}\leqslant  \frac 2{ |f(x_0)|^2} \frac \varepsilon 2|f(x_0)|^2 \\
&=\varepsilon
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $g$ is continuous af $f(a)$, then $g(f(a))$ is continuous at $a$. This is an easy consequence of the definition of continuity. Just take $g(x) = 1/x$, which is continuous at $f(x_0)$.

Comment: Although this is true, it sort of defeats the purpose of the exercise: one should include a proof of the fact composition of functions is continuous, and that $1/x$ is continuous at every nonzero $x$. Showing this last claim is "as easy" as showing that if $f$ is continuous at a point and nonzero there, so is $1/f$ (which is what I did.)